# How do I update grub2 on USB drive?

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader, usb-storage, grub2

I have a usb drive with grub2 installed to the MBR. I'd like to add some custom entries to the boot menu but I can't figure out how to run `sudo update-grub` and have it affect the USB drive and not the grub2 on my HD.

How do I do this in ubuntu?

I have both a live ubuntu (on the USB device) and an installed version on my HD.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting a bit with how to accomplish this, but I think your best bet is to simply disconnect the hard drive and thus boot with USB drive connected only. Then update grub as normal.